# Submit Array Type Doctrine Form

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, doctrine, symfony

I searched a lot before asking (never is enough) so I hope this isn't a duplicate question.

Well here I go:

I am developing a REST API with symfony (using FOSRestBundle and JMSSerializerBundle). I try to make a POST query with the follow body:

```
{
"name":"Planta 1",
"parentJoint": null,
"owner": 1,
"ownerCRUD":{
    "C":"0",
    "R":"0",
    "U":"0",
    "D":"0"
}
```

To fill the follow Doctrine's Entity

```
<?php

    namespace AppBundle\Entity;
    use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

    /**
    * Joint
    *
    * @ORM\Table(name="joint")
    * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\JointRepository")
    */
    class Joint
    {

    (...)

    /**
     * @var array
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="owner_crud", type="array",nullable = false)
     */
    private $ownerCRUD;

    /** 
     * Set ownerCRUD
     *
     * @param array $ownerCRUD
     * @return Joint
     */
    public function setOwnerCRUD($ownerCRUD)
    {
        $this->ownerCRUD = $ownerCRUD;        
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get ownerCRUD
     *
     * @return array 
     */
    public function getOwnerCRUD()
    {
        return $this->ownerCRUD;
    }

    public function __toString() 
    {
        return 'any string';
    }
}
```

I try to make it through this controller's function:

```
 /**
 * Description: This method create and persist in database a new Joint Element
 * 
 * @ApiDoc(
 * )
 *
 * @var Request $request    
 */
public function postJointAction(Request $request)
{ 
    try {
        $parameters = $request->request->all();
        dump($parameters);
        $joint = new Joint();
        $form = $this->createForm('AppBundle\Form\JointType', $joint);
        $form->submit($parameters, 'POST');
        dump($form);
        if ($form->isValid()) {
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $joint = $form->getData();
            $em->persist($joint);
            $em->flush($joint);
            $joint = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Joint')->find($joint->getId());        
            //Create a View
            $templateData = array('joint' => $joint);
            $view = $this->view($templateData,200)
            ->setTemplate("joint/show.html.twig")
            ->setTemplateVar('joint')
            ->setTemplateData($templateData)
            ->setData($templateData)
        ;
        return $this->handleView($view);
        }                     
    } catch (InvalidFormException $exception) {
        return $exception->getForm();            
    }
}
```

And my form is like this:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

class JointType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
        ->add('name')
        ->add('parentJoint')
        ->add('owner')
        ->add('ownerCRUD') ;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\Joint',
            'csrf_protection' => false
        ));
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getBlockPrefix()
    {
        return 'appbundle_joint';
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return "";
    }
}
```

**The problem is that the form doesn't get the ownerCRUD fields correctly, the form assumes that are extra fields and not the properly fields**

```
This form should not contain extra fields.  ownerCRUD   
Symfony\Component\Validator\ConstraintViolation
Object(Symfony\Component\Form\Form).children[ownerCRUD] = [C => 0, R => 0, U => 0, D => 0]
```

Thanks in advance

My twig file

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}

{% block body %}
<h1>Joint</h1>

<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th>Id</th>
            <td>{{ joint.id }}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <td>{{ joint.name }}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<ul>
    <li>
        <a href="{{ path('get_joints') }}">Back to the list</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="{{ path('put_joint', { 'joint': joint.id }) }}">Edit</a>
    </li>
</ul>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Can you please show us form of  `twig` file?

Comment: Setting the field name to `""` seem pretty invalid :-/ Can you submit `['formName' => $parameters]`?

Comment: I put my twig file but i think that is not the problem, i use it only when the data are stored to report the success

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your body seems invalid to me. Since ownerCRUD is supposed to be an array your body should looks like this:

```
{
    "name":"Planta 1",
    "parentJoint": null,
    "owner": 1,
    "ownerCRUD":[
        "0",
        "0",
        "0",
        "0"
    ]
}
```

Notice the [ ] instead of { } around "C":"0", "R":"0", "U":"0", "D":"0"

**EDIT:**

removed keys "C", "R", "U", "D"

Comment: You're right, you should only keep the values 0, 0, 0, 0

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to transform your entity..

My alternative :

**Convert your datatype for "ownerCRUD" to a string value..**

*Joint entity :*

```
 /**
     * @var array
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="owner_crud", type="string",nullable = false)
     */
    private $ownerCRUD;


    /** 
     * Set ownerCRUD
     *
     * @param array $ownerCRUD
     * @return Joint
     */
    public function setOwnerCRUD(array $ownerCRUD)
    {
        $this->ownerCRUD = $ownerCRUD;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get ownerCRUD
     *
     * @return array 
     */
    public function getOwnerCRUD()
    {
        return array($this->ownerCRUD);
    }
```

Comment: Well your solution is being the best by now. But i got an error :"array to string conversión" meanwhile I am storing the data. I made a little change :       `
    public function setOwnerCRUD(array $ownerCRUD)
    {
        $this->ownerCRUD =serialize($ownerCRUD);
    
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get ownerCRUD
     *
     * @return array 
     */
    public function getOwnerCRUD()
    {
        return unserialize($this->ownerCRUD);
    }`  and that is working to store the data, but when i recover by GET don't recover like an correct array only like a text

Comment: Ok ! Did you try with @Olivier Chretien's syntax ? He's right `[` stands for `array` and `{` stands for `object`